# Brew install a branch / fork

Tags: homebrew

This might sound like a silly question.

I can't figure out how (if possible) to use brew on OSX to install an official branch of a GIT rep.

Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew can only install software that someone has created a recipe for. It isn't a general-purpose installer.

If you know how to install the software in the Git repository, you may be able to [create a Homebrew recipe to install it](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md). If you don't know how to do that, though, Homebrew won't be able to help you.